# Correct statement of Birkhoff's theorem (spherically symmetric does not imply static?)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, symmetry, time

If I understand correctly, the appropriate statement of Birkhoff's theorem in general relativity is that

> The Schwarzschild metric is the unique spherically symmetric vacuum
> solution.

(Or we might say it is the unique family of solutions, with a different solution for each mass.) See e.g. [Carroll](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll7.html) for statement and argument.  Meanwhile, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) (as of March 10, 2021) and other sources tend to state Birkoff's theorem as

> Any spherically symmetric vacuum solution must be static and asymptotically flat.

However, if I understand correctly, the [maximally extended Schwarzschild solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates#The_maximally_extended_Schwarzschild_solution) is *not* static.  While it is static when restricted to the exterior region, it is not static on the interior.  (The timelike Killing field, which renders the exterior static, becomes spacelike in the interior.) **Is the Wikipedia statement therefore incorrect, with the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution providing a counterexample?**

n.b. It's easy to confuse the metric in the interior of the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution with the so-called "[interior Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric)"; the latter is a different geometry altogether, and not a vacuum solution.

**Update:**  I have become more confident that the above comments are correct, and Wikipedia is incorrect.  For instance, according to [Schmidt](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9709071.pdf),

> ...it is generally known that the popular formulation “every spherically symmetric vacuum solution is static” is misleading, because inside the horizon, the Schwarzschild black hole is not static.

Indeed, the statement of Birkhoff's theorem in Hawking and Ellis (Appendix B, p372) is that any sufficiently smooth vacuum solution that is spherically symmetric in some patch must be locally equivalent to part of the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution.

**I would still appreciate expert corroboration, and maybe someone should edit Wikipedia.**

Comment: Nice to see that EmmyNoether is catching up with Einstein's theorys :P

Comment: You may find this relevant to your question: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S2010194512006642